# @ComponentScan doesn't work in Spring boot AutoConfiguration class?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to create a new starter. I have a business module, say ProjectManager, that contains some classes annotated with @Component. Following the tutorial, I created an autoconfigure module, it contains an AutoConfiguration class. Firstly, I tried to use @ComponentSan to find the beans in my business module.

```
@ComponentScan(value = {"com.foo.project"})
@ConditionalOnClass({Project.class})
@Configuration
public class ProjectAutoConfiguration {
    ....

}
```

But it doesn't work. I have to add additional configuration class as below:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(value = {"com.foo.project"})
@MapperScan(value = {"com.foo.project"})
public class ProjectConfig {
}
```

And then import it into AutoConfiguration class like below:

```
@Import(ProjectConfig.class)
@ConditionalOnClass({Project.class})
@Configuration
public class ProjectAutoConfiguration {
    ....

}
```

That works. But according to the spring [doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-auto-configuration.html).

> auto-configuration is implemented with standard @Configuration classes

So my question is, Why @ComponentScan doesn't work here ? Did I make something wrong? Or it is by design ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

you have to use the compentscan annotation into the main class. Here a sample code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.foo.project")
public class MainApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(MainApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MainApplication().configure(new SpringApplicationBuilder(MainApplication.class)).run(args);
    }
}
```

Cheers

Comment: You mean, the class with main method?

Comment: It does work to add it to main class. So do you mean @ComponentScan only work with main class in spring boot?

Comment: i don't think. But it is better. The main class is in the root of the project. So the componentscan scans the packages and those packages are in the subfolder of the root.

Answer (score 8):

*Automatic everything* requires the Application class (annotated with @SpringBootApplication) to be in a "higher" package than the components you want to scan.

Use:

```
package com.example.foo;
```

for your application and put components in a package like:

```
package com.example.foo.entities;
```

See also https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-using-springbootapplication-annotation.html

Comment: great. instead of adding scan annotation. your answer is very good

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with following?

```
@ConditionalOnClass({Project.class})
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(value = {"com.foo.project"})
public class ProjectAutoConfiguration {
    ....

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was developing a SDK project. It needs the application which depends on the SDK to scan for beans beneath specific package in the SDK during start period.

Anotate with @ComponentScan on autowire configuration class doesn't take effect.

Then I am trying to use @Import annotation to import a class implemented interface [ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar.html)(Interface to be implemented by types that register additional bean definitions when processing @Configuration classes. Useful when operating at the bean definition level (as opposed to @Bean method/instance level) is desired or necessary).

Within ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar implementation class, I register a class annotated with @ComponentScan as bean. Run application again, it works as expected.

**Codes below:**

AutoConfiguration Class:

```
@Configuration
@Import(TestConfigRegistar.Registrar.class)
public class TestClientAutoCofiguration {

}
```

Registar class:

```
public class TestConfigRegistar {
public static class Registrar implements ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar {
    private static final String BEAN_NAME = "componentScanConfig";

    @Override
    public void registerBeanDefinitions(AnnotationMetadata annotationMetadata, 
                                                 BeanDefinitionRegistry registry) {
        GenericBeanDefinition beanDefinition = new GenericBeanDefinition();
        beanDefinition.setBeanClass(ComponentScanConfig.class);
        beanDefinition.setRole(BeanDefinition.ROLE_INFRASTRUCTURE);
        beanDefinition.setSynthetic(true);
        registry.registerBeanDefinition(BEAN_NAME, beanDefinition);
    }
}
}
```

Class with @ComponentScan annotation

```
// Leave an empty value of @ComponentScan will let spring scan
// current class package and all sub-packages
@ComponentScan
public class ComponentScanConfig {
}
```

I believe that the point is that beans annotated with @ComponentScan must be defined at definition level (as opposed to @Bean method/instance level). Please correct me if I'm wrong, Thanks.